# How to specify Python type hint on inherited classmethod?

Tags: python, type-hinting

In Python 3.5, I'd like to use type hinting on a class method that returns a new instance of a class.

For example, I've got the following two classes:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def new_thing(cls):
        return cls()

class B(A):
    pass
```

I'd like to add a type hint to `new_thing` to specify that it returns an instance of the class it's called from.

The closest solution I've found is to use `TypeVar`, e.g.:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class A:
    @classmethod
    def new_thing(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cls()
```

However, this doesn't indicate any constraints on the type of `cls`, whereas `cls` should always be a instance of `A` or one of its subclasses (i.e. there's nothing to hint that `cls` should be callable here).

Is there some way to achieve this? `TypeVar` has a `bound` argument, so a first thought was:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)
```

but this doesn't work, as `A` isn't defined when the `TypeVar` is declared (and I can't declare `A` without the `T` first being defined).

Comment: I don't think the dupe exactly answers your question, but in any case, you were pretty close -- the only thing you need to change is to do is to make your typevar to use a [forward reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) -- that is, do `T = TypeVar('T', bound='A')`.

Comment: In python < 3.7 I'd use:
`from typing import Type

class A:
    @classmethod
    def new_thing(cls: Type['A']) -> 'A':
        return cls()`